# UICollectionView assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _endItemAnimations]

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

Long story short, I'm simply doing this:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:insPoint inSection:0];
[self.m_orders insertObject:orderRecord atIndex:insPoint];
[self.m_collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]];


Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 0.  The number of items contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of items contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of items inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of items moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).
```

There are no issues if I changed it to reloadData but that isn't ideal.

If I called it in several successions it would crash. If it's only one time then there isn't any issue.

Am I missing something here? I thought the numbers match? What would be the issue here?

Comment: refer link(which provides info related to your issue) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19199985/invalid-update-invalid-number-of-items-on-uicollectionview

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm you're actually crashing on the `insertItemsAtIndexPaths:` call? Assuming yes, the error code is specifically telling you that by the time you call `insertItemsAtIndexPaths:` on your collection view, the number of items in that section hasn't changed. Can you post your collection view data source methods (eg `collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:`) so we can confirm you're handling that correctly?

Also, can you confirm this is all happening on the main thread? If so, one of two things are happening here:
1) You're modifying your data source elsewhere before this code is hit.
2) You're performing other collection view update(s) (inserts/removes) before this code is hit.

Comment: Yes, I am crashing on that call.

`- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.m_orders.count;
}`

All of it is happening on the main thread. As you have stated, I believe there could be some data being moved around (deleted an object) in self.m_orders elsewhere, hence when the insert code is hit, theres an error. I will have to take a closer look when I have time though, for now I'm using reloadData. Thank you very much for your suggestions as to why it broke!!