# UICollectionView - insertItems(at: indexPath) not working

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have an array with some elements in it which my `UICollectionView` displays. I then go and fetch more elements and append it to my array. I want to then tell the `UICollectionView` that elements have been added to the datasource and to update the UI.

I tried this but it is not working:

```
// Add more data to my existing array
myArray.append(contentsOf: moreElements)
let indexPath = [IndexPath(row: myArray.count-1, section: 0)]
myCollectionView.insertItems(at: indexPath)
```

I get this [error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19199985/7842955) but I am not sure if I am doing something wrong.

EDIT: I do NOT want to use `myCollectionView.reloadData()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your issue is that you need an `IndexPath` for each item you are adding to the collection view. You add multiple objects to `myArray` but then you only pass one `IndexPath` to `insertItems`. And this is the cause of the error.

Try the following:

```
var paths = [IndexPath]()
for item in 0..<moreElements.count {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: item + myArray.count, section: 0)
    paths.append(indexPath)
}

myArray.append(contentsOf: moreElements)
myCollectionView.insertItems(at: paths)
```

Comment: I'm getting an error because I have a footer: `no UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes instance for -layoutAttributesForSupplementaryElementOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter`

Comment: That's a whole new issue beyond the one you asked in this question. Focus on one problem as a time.

Comment: Ok. Your solution works great (when there is no footer). I will have to figure out what else is going on with my footer.