# 'Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 0 in my collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

When I press the `editButton` on my app and attempt to delete a cell in my collectionView I receive the following error message:

> 'Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 0.  The number of
>   items contained in an existing section after the update (3) must be
>   equal to the number of items contained in that section before the
>   update (3), plus or minus the number of items inserted or deleted from
>   that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of
>   items moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

After reading through [other similar posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19199985/invalid-update-invalid-number-of-items-on-uicollectionview) I was still unsure how to apply a solution to this issue. I do see the files being deleted from the FileManager because I have the directory open in the Finder, but I'm at a loss as to how to get the collectionView to be in sync with the number of files in the FileManager.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioRecorderDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var audioRecorder: AVAudioRecorder!
    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!
    var numberOfRecordings = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var recordButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var editButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        recordButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        editButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10


         // Set the numberOfRecordings to be exactly the number of files stored in the File Manager so that they're in sync.
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let documentsURL = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        do {
            let fileURLs = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsHiddenFiles)
            numberOfRecordings = fileURLs.count
        } catch {
            print("Error while enumerating files \(documentsURL.path): \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

    }

    // Let's get the directory where we're going to store the recordings
    func getDirectory() -> URL {
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let documentDirectory = paths[0]
        return documentDirectory
    }

    // Let's create a genearl alert to display error messages
    func displayAlert(title: String, message: String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .default, handler: nil))
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    //MARK: - Record Button Methods
    @IBAction func record(_ sender: Any) {

        if audioRecorder == nil {
            numberOfRecordings += 1
            let fileURL = getDirectory().appendingPathComponent("\(numberOfRecordings).m4a")
            let settings = [
                AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
                AVSampleRateKey: 12000,
                AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
                AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
            ]

            do {
                audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: fileURL, settings: settings)
                audioRecorder.delegate = self
                audioRecorder.record()
                recordButton.setTitle("Stop Recording", for: .normal)
            } catch {
                displayAlert(title: "Oops!", message: "Recording Failed")
            }
        } else {
            audioRecorder.stop()
            audioRecorder = nil
            UserDefaults.standard.set(numberOfRecordings, forKey: "numberOfRecordings")
            recordButton.setTitle("Start Recording", for: .normal)
            myCollectionView.reloadData()

        }

    }


    //MARK: - Collection View Setup
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return numberOfRecordings
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! RecordingCollectionViewCell
        cell.recordingLabel.text = String(indexPath.row + 1)
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        cell.delegate = self as RecordingCellDelegate
        return cell
    }

    //MARK: - Audio Player
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let path = getDirectory().appendingPathComponent("\(indexPath.row + 1).m4a")

        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: path)
            audioPlayer.volume = 1.0
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayer.play()
        } catch let error {
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    //MARK: - Edit Button Methods
    @IBAction func editButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if editButton.titleLabel?.text == "Edit" {
            recordButton.isEnabled = isEditing
            editButton.setTitle("Stop Editing", for: .normal)
            if let indexPaths = myCollectionView?.indexPathsForVisibleItems {
                for indexPath in indexPaths {
                    if let cell = myCollectionView?.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? RecordingCollectionViewCell {
                        cell.isEditing = !isEditing
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            editButton.setTitle("Edit", for: .normal)
            if let indexPaths = myCollectionView?.indexPathsForVisibleItems {
                for indexPath in indexPaths {
                    if let cell = myCollectionView?.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? RecordingCollectionViewCell {
                        cell.isEditing = isEditing
                    }
                }
            }
        }


    }


}


extension ViewController: RecordingCellDelegate {
    func delete(cell: RecordingCollectionViewCell) {
        if let indexPath = myCollectionView?.indexPath(for: cell) {
            // 1. Delete the recording from the File Manager
            let fileManager = FileManager.default
            let fileURL = getDirectory().appendingPathComponent("\(indexPath.row + 1).m4a")
            do {
                try fileManager.removeItem(at: fileURL)

            }   catch let error {
                print("File not found: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                displayAlert(title: "Oops!", message: "File not found: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }

            // 2. Delete it in the collectionView
            myCollectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never update your data model. Beside deleting the file and telling the collection view that an item has been deleted, you also need to update the model used by the collection view. This means you need to update `numberOfRecordings` (before calling `myCollectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])`.

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly states that *in order to add new rows or delete existing rows*, you need to make the same changes to the corresponding array i.e. **numberOfRecordings** as well.

Like , if you are *deleting 1 row*, then you need to make the same changes to the array (like, earlier it had 3 rows (and the array had 3 items as well), and now you want to delete 1 row, so you need to delete the same number of items (i.e. 1) from the corresponding array(numberOfRecordings) as well) .

Same applies for addition as well .

> Perform addition to or deletion from an array before making any changes to
>   the table view with `tableView.deleteRows()` or
>   `tableView.insertRows()`