# iOS UICollectionView crash - NSInternalInconsistencyException reason Invalid batch updates detected

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to update the collectionview after a network call to insert more elements into the collectionview. There is only one section (section 0). The crash was very hard to reproduce and I can't tell exactly why this is happening. The code is also written in a way suggested in Raywenderlich's [answer](https://forums.kodeco.com/t/collection-view-deleting-cell-error/33196) and as suggested by this stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71346797/1253102)

Here is my code:

```
func process(_ difference: [CollectionDifference<User>.Change]?) {
        guard let difference = difference, !difference.isEmpty else {
            updateDataSource()
            collectionView.reloadData()
            return
        }
        let deleting = difference.contains { change in
            if case let .remove(offset: _, element: _, associatedWith: associatedWith) = change {
                return associatedWith == nil
            }
            return false
        }

        let inserting = difference.contains { change in
            if case let .insert(offset: _, element: _, associatedWith: associatedWith) = change {
                return associatedWith == nil
            }
            return false
        }

        isCollectionViewUpdating = true
        collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
            updateDataSource()
            for change in difference {
                switch change {
                case let .insert(offset: offset, element: recommendation, associatedWith: _):
                    collectionView.insertItems(at: [IndexPath(row: offset, section: 0)])
                case let .remove(offset: offset, element: _, associatedWith: _):
                    collectionView.deleteItems(at: [IndexPath(row: offset, section: 0)])
                }
            }
        }, completion: { [weak self] _ in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.isCollectionViewUpdating = false

            self.finalizingIndexPaths.removeAll()
            if deleting {
                self.paginate()
            } else if inserting {
                self.delegate?.didInsertInCollectionView()
            }
        })
    }
```

and this is the error message I run into

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid batch updates detected: the number of sections and/or items returned by the data source before and/or after performing the batch updates are inconsistent with the updates.
Data source before updates = { 1 section with item counts: [16] }
Data source after updates = { 1 section with item counts: [16] }
Updates = [
    Insert item (0 - 0),
    Insert item (0 - 1),
    Insert item (0 - 2),
    Insert item (0 - 3),
    Insert item (0 - 4),
    Insert item (0 - 5),
    Insert item (0 - 6),
    Insert item (0 - 7),
    Insert item (0 - 8),
    Insert item (0 - 9),
    Insert item (0 - 10),
    Insert item (0 - 11),
    Insert item (0 - 12),
    Insert item (0 - 13),
    Insert item (0 - 14),
    Insert item (0 - 15)
]
```

Also this particular viewcontroller containing the collectionView is added as a child viewcontroller to its parent viewcontroller. The parent viewcontroller is part of a tab bar controller.

There are call backs that deals with uicollectionview

```
public func willBecomeActive() {
   view.layoutIfNeeded()
   collectionView.reloadData()
   // need to add this empty performBatchUpdates, otherwise the cells don't
   // come on screen in tests
   collectionView.performBatchUpdates({}, completion: nil)
}

public func didResignActive() {
    collectionView.reloadData()
}

override public func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    collectionViewFlowLayout.updateItemSize()

    // helps to correctly resizes the cells.
    UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
       collectionView.performBatchUpdates({}, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Can someone spot the issue with my code and help?

I tried to load collectionview with new users and replace the old ones. I was expecting that the new users are inserted successfully. But I sometimes run into a crash which is hard to explain. The error message for the crash is above